# Delete data from Temp table if already exists in DB

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called employee.

```
Employee
------------
ID
Name
Age
```

To insert data to Employee table, i have a Temp Table with same table structure, say #TempEmployee

```
#TempEmployee
------------
ID
Name
Age
DOB
```

I would like to delete data from table, if the data is already there in Employee Table. I tried below script but it didn't work.

```
DELETE a
FROM #TempEmployee AS a
INNER JOIN Employee b 
ON b.Id = a.Id AND b.Name = a.Name
```

Please help to rectify this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what does it didn't work mean-syntax error or logical error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another syntax:

```
DELETE #TempEmployee
FROM #TempEmployee AS a
INNER JOIN Employee b 
ON b.Id = a.Id AND b.Name = a.Name
```

Let me show an example:

At first, we create persistent table `Employee` and fill this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    Id INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Age INT
)


INSERT INTO dbo.Employee
(
    Id,
    Name,
    Age
)
VALUES
  (1, 'Person_1', 1)
, (4, 'Person_4', 4)
, (5, 'Person_5', 5)
```

Then we create temporary table and fill it by data:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempEmployee
(
    Id INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Age INT
)

INSERT INTO #TempEmployee
(
    Id,
    Name,
    Age
)
VALUES
  (1, 'Person_1', 1)
, (2, 'Person_2', 2)
, (3, 'Person_3', 3)
```

The next move will be deletion of data from temporary table:

```
DELETE #TempEmployee
FROM #TempEmployee AS a
INNER JOIN Employee b 
ON b.Id = a.Id AND b.Name = a.Name
```

The output will be of  `SELECT * FROM #TempEmployee`:

```
Id    Name     Age
2   Person_2    2
3   Person_3    3
```

Comment: Will it work if the temp table contains extra columns?

Comment: @Erma yeah, the main condition to delete is `ON b.Id = a.Id AND b.Name = a.Name `.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
DELETE a
FROM #TempEmployee AS a
INNER JOIN Employee b 
ON b.Id = a.Id AND b.Name = a.Name
```

Comment: I tried given script.. but it didn't work

Comment: provide your sample data and it should definitely work @Erma

Comment: In my temp table i have extra column, is that why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bear in mind that there is one temporary table per active user except if you use the double #.
That means that if two users are active and creating the Temporary table, they will create separate copies of #TempEmployee. If one launches the script to remove the ones already inserted, that will not affect the other user.
Additionally, I would recommend you a different to call the removal process (asuming that the ID is the primary key):

```
DELETE a
FROM #TempEmployee 
WHERE id IN (
SELECT ID 
FROM Employee)
```